# How to store an Arraylist's toString object into a file

Tags: java

So I have...

```
 List<ClassName> x = new ArrayList<ClassName>();
```

This stores a class reference into an ArrayList. One of the methods inside 
ClassName is toString. I want to be able to write all ArrayList indexes toString
methods into a text file.

```
Formatter f = new Formatter("saved.txt");
for (int i = 0 ; i<ClassName.size() ; i++) {
     f.format("%s%n",ClassName.get(i)); 
  }
f.close();
```

However, when I open the text file, it is empty.
Thanks

Comment: do you actually have values inside your ClassName list?

Answer (score -1):

You are not flushing (*saving*) the file, thus nothing is saved. To put it out there, it works like the following:

First the Formatter writes to a buffer, and when you flush the formatter it will write that buffer to the file and then clear this buffer.

So in short, call `f.flush();` before `f.close();`

When you try to flush the formatter after it has been flushed, you will get a `FormatterClosedException`. Everything what is stated here is in the [documentation of `Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#flush())

Comment: No need to call flush() explicitly. If you look inside formatter, you will see that it uses BufferedWriter, which flushes automatically when close() is called.